# Is it possible to use DisplayFor() from within the EditorFor template control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using `EditorFor()` helper to render edit template in my view and I would like to call the `DisplayFor()` inside this template to render out the Display template.

Like this

this is inside the /Shared/EditorTemplates/Client.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<BusinessNext.Models.Ef.Client>" %>
<%: Html.DisplayFor(client=>client) %>
```

In the DisplayFor template I render out client's properties. DisplayFor template works perfectly fine when called from everywhere else but from EditorFor template it doesn't render out anything. It seems that the `DisplayFor()` call never actually gets to the DisplayFor template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that the only way is to use a partial:

```
<%= Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Client.ascx", Model) %>
```

Comment: I tried with <% Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Shared.Views.DisplayTemplates.Client, Model); %> 
since I use T4MVC and it doesn't find the view user control. It returns the standard error, searching the directories and not finding it. Otherwise, my T4MVC have worked all the time so far.

Comment: neither does this, same error <%=Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.DisplayTemplates.Client) %> - is there something special about those two folders?

Comment: @mare, no, there shouldn't be anything special. Try passing a string to see if it makes any difference. Also what does the searched location in the error message tell you? Do they give some hints?

Comment: Somehow using T4MVC strong typed classes doesn't work in this case but it does if I provide the path. This does introduce two *hacks* into my code: 1) I was just starting to use DisplayFor and EditorFor in most cases, now I have an exception to this, 2) another exception to my rules is this provision of path to the Partial or RenderPartial helpers. Any comments on that?

Comment: this now seems to be fixed in MVC4 - displayFor's can be nested

Answer (score 1):

It can be debatable if it is a good idea to template complicated objects, or if my approach to nested templates is a hack or not.  The advantage of this is having a single template for the parent and child can both have templates rather than having to choose/use partial views.

All that aside, **templated views can be nested, if** you use a partial view as an go between.

The outside template will have something like below where you want to place the inner template:

```
Html.RenderPartial("SharedDisplayGoBetweenForFoo", item);
```

The shared partial would look like this:

```
@model Foo

@Html.DisplayFor(a => a);
```

The inner template would then be called and would look like any other.