# Nested @Html.DisplayFor(model => baseClass, "BaseClass") for base class template not rendering

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-3, nested, razor

Several sub-classes (e.g. *Cheese*) share common properties derived from a base class (*Product*) with properties like *SKU*, *Name* and *Description*.

To avoid duplication when rendering display/editor templates, I want each sub-class template (*Cheese.cshtml*) to render its unique fields below that of its shared common base class template (*Product.cshtml*).

However, casting from the derived class to the base class `(Product)cheese` and trying to display its template inside the sub-class template has no effect.

### DisplayTemplate File structure:

```
.\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates
    .\Product.cshtml -- renders common base class fields
    .\Cheese.cshtml -- renders unique class fields and calls Product.cshtml
```

### `Cheese.chtml`:

```
@model Application.Data.Models.Cheese

@{
    var product = (Application.Data.Models.Part)Model;
}

Base Product Fields:
@Html.DisplayFor(x => products, "Product") @* no effect! *@

<div class="field">
    <div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.UniqueProperty)</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.UniqueProperty)</div>
</div>
```

Casting to the base class and rendering the *Product.cshtml* template works fine from a View, but not from within the sub-class template.

How can I render a common template for my base class from within my sub-class templates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Solution Found

`@Html.DisplayFor(...)` [cannot be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845753/is-it-possible-to-use-displayfor-from-within-the-editorfor-template-control), so you have to use `@Html.Partial` in your derived template like so:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Product.cshtml", product) %>
```

Or, if your file structure allows it, a more terse path:

```
@Html.Partial("DisplayTemplates/Product", product)
```

Comment: this now seems to be fixed in MVC4 - displayFor's can be nested

Comment: Is it? I use MVC5 and I still cannot nest them

Comment: I'm using Razor Pages in AspNet 6 and nesting doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Using Razor Pages (in AspNet 6) I needed to use Html.RenderPartial instead of Html.Partial, but solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It can be debatable if it is a good idea to template complicated objects, or if my approach to nested templates is a hack or not.  The advantage of this is having a single template for the parent and child can both have templates rather than having to choose/use partial views.

All that aside, **templated views can be nested, if** you use a partial view as an go between.

The outside template will have something like below where you want to place the inner template:

```
Html.RenderPartial("SharedDisplayGoBetweenForFoo", item);
```

The shared partial would look like this:

```
@model Foo

@Html.DisplayFor(a => a);
```

The inner template would then be called and would look like any other.

So your example would look like

Cheese.cshtml:

```
@model Application.Data.Models.Cheese

@{
    var product = (Application.Data.Models.Part)Model;
}

Base Product Fields:
@Html.DisplayFor(x => products, "Product") @* no effect! *@

<div class="field">
    <div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UniqueProperty)</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Html.RenderPartial("SharedPartialProductGobetween", Model.UniqueProperty)</div>
</div>
```

SharedPartialProductGobetween.cshtml:

```
@model Product

@Html.DisplayFor(a => a);
```

Your Product Template wouldn't change.