# Can a display template be invoked from within an editor template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a display template in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` named `ImpactMatrix.cshtml`.  It accepts a nullable int and renders a two-dimensional matrix with the selected number highlighted:

```
@model int?

@{
    var matrix = ImpactMatrix.GetMatrix();
}   

<div class="impactmatrix">
  <table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    { 
        <tr>
          @for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
          {
              var cell = matrix[i, j];
              <td data-color="@cell.Color" 
                class="matrix @(Model == cell.Value ? cell.Color.ToString() : "")">
                    @cell.Value
              </td>
          }
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

It's easily reusable and works great.  I can invoke it within my view like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.ImpactFactor, "ImpactMatrix")
```

Now I've decided to extend that and make it an editor as well.  The idea is to add a hidden input for the selected number and wrap the input along with the matrix template with a div.  From there it should be a simple matter to use Javascript to interact with my display grid and populate the hidden input.

I've created an editor template, also named `ImpactMatrix.cshtml`, within my `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder.  Here's the code:

```
@model int?

<div class="impactmatrix-editor">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m, "ImpactMatrix")
</div>
```

My problem is that the hidden input renders correctly, but the nested display template does not render inside my editor template.  Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it **is not currently supported**.

However, I have found a solution using the `Html.Partial` in this article: [Nested @Html.DisplayFor(model => baseClass, "BaseClass") for base class template not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291808/nested-html-displayformodel-baseclass-baseclass-for-base-class-template)

Rewrite you editor template like this:

```
@model int?

<div class="impactmatrix-editor">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m)
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ImpactMatrix.cshtml", Model)
</div>
```

*Note: @Paul Hadfield commented on this issue in the article I have mentioned above, that this issue has been fixed for ASP MVC 4. But even though I run this version on my PC, I was not able to make nested templates working.*

Comment: Thanks for the info and link!  I figured it was unsupported in MVC3.  I'll have to try it in MVC4 and see what happens.

Comment: NP. Give an echo if you were successfull with MVC4 and nested templates. Anyway, the workaround I showed, is working for all versions since MVC2.

Comment: The workaround works for me. Thanks.  I have MVC4 too and the nested templates dont work.  This is a major limitation and needs to be fixed.

Comment: I had to use this workaround when trying to nest a display template in another display template for the same model.