# Using DisplayFor inside a display template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a htmlhelper extension to reduce the amount of repetitive markup when creating forms:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderField<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    return htmlHelper.DisplayFor(expression, "formfield");
}
```

The idea being that inside my views I can just write `@Html.RenderField(x=>x.MyFieldName)` and it will print the label and the field's content with the appropriate `div` tags in place already.

Inside the displaytemplates folder I have created formfield.cshtml containing the following:

```
<div class="display-group">
<div class="display-label">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x)
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't appear that it is possible to nest DisplayFor inside a display template (it doesn't render anything). I don't want to just using `@Model` because then I won't get checkboxes for boolean values, calendar controls for dates etc.

Is there a good way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest `DisplayFor()`. See here: [Is it possible to use DisplayFor() from within the EditorFor template control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845753/is-it-possible-to-use-displayfor-from-within-the-editorfor-template-control)

Have you considered `Html.DisplayForModel()`? Explanation and sample code can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430907(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Do you mean Html.DisplayForModel() with a parameter? Cause with out it I'd expect it to do something like infinite recursion should it work in a DisplayTemplate